# Updated Angular version causes error on ngMessages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I updated AngularJs version from 1.3 to 1.4. 
It causes an error as,

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression
>   [{{frmname}}.emailAddress.$error] starting at
>   [{frmname}}.emailAddress.$error].

It works perfectly in Angular 1.3

```
<form name="{{frmname}}">
  <h1>My form name = {{frmname}}</h1>
  <div class="field">
  <label for="emailAddress">Enter your email address:</label>
  <input type="email" name="emailAddress" ng-model="email" required />
    <div ng-messages="{{frmname}}.emailAddress.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">
        You forgot to enter your email address...
      </div>
      <div ng-message="email">
        You did not enter your email address correctly...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[FIDDLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/VkW0jN6zqthlHmF5aI6H?p=preview)

Comment: What version exactly were you using before and are using now?

Comment: Its working fine in 1.3.15 
https://plnkr.co/edit/6UqmxJ0c8RsGzYpK6k6Y?p=preview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution,

Add a function for getting ng-messages attribute value.

```
<div ng-messages="getMessages('emailAddress')">
  <div ng-message="required">
    You forgot to enter your email address...
  </div>
  <div ng-message="email">
    You did not enter your email address correctly...
  </div>
</div>
```

Declare the function inside your controller or directive.

```
$scope.getMessages = function (el) {
  return $scope.$eval($scope.frmname)[el].$error;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/VkW0jN6zqthlHmF5aI6H)

Comment: Explain why it's negative answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to set your form name from a dynamic variable then you could use `ng-form` to validate your inputs inside the actual form.

Basic html:

```
<form name="{{formName}}" novalidate>

  <ng-form name="emailError">
    <div ng-messages="emailError.emailAddress.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
      <label for="emailAddress">Enter your email address:</label>
      <input type="email" name="emailAddress" ng-model="email" minlength="5" required />
      <div ng-messages="emailError.emailAddress.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    </div>
  </ng-form>

  <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Q0ifmRXKkLfwKGNqv8p4?p=preview

Official documentation of ngForm: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm